# How can I create a sequence generator in DataFlow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Using PTransforms, I'm generating say 1 million objects. However, I need to label these objects with individual unique numbers from 1 to 1 million. There is NO specified order that these objets need to be generated, but the sequence number should range continuously from 1 to 1 million.

So, I need what in a db world would be an "autonum" function or also known as a "sequence generator". Is there a way to accomplish thin in google cloud dataflow?

The only ideas I came up with is to:

a) store all of the objects as a signle PCollectionView object and then traverse this list in order and assign a new hashmap which has the sequenceKey and the object value. This is not super efficient, and has problems when trying to store all million objects in memory, but it is a workaround that should work.

or

b) maybe use some sort of memcache service that is accessible from all notes and do an atomic read-increment from it? (Not sure how to do this, but it might be possible.) But, this feels like a lot of coding for a simple sequence generator (also, I'm not sure if performance may be poor since everything may get bottlenecks by the seq generator call)

c) remove requirement that the sequence numbers are contiguous, and then do something similar to "b" above.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of behavior can be simply supported with stateful processing in Beam's Java SDK. This is because state information can be kept *accross bundles*, so you can number the elements of your whole PCollection.

You can read more about it [in this blog post](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/02/13/stateful-processing.html).

A DoFn that can do this is the following:

```
new DoFn<KV<MyKey, MyValue>, KV<Integer, KV<MyKey, MyValue>>>() {

  // A state cell holding a single Integer per key+window
  @StateId("index")
  private final StateSpec<Object, ValueState<Integer>> indexSpec = 
      StateSpecs.value(VarIntCoder.of());

  @ProcessElement
  public void processElement(
      ProcessContext context,
      @StateId("index") ValueState<Integer> index) {
    int current = firstNonNull(index.read(), 0);
    context.output(KV.of(current, context.element()));
    index.write(current+1);
  }
}
```

Comment: This will number only values within each key, but it does not improve over the PCollectionView solution if you need to number all values in a collection.

Comment: You can make up a key and use it on all the values of the `PCollection`.

Comment: Yes, but in that case you don't need the state API - you can just iterate over the Iterable<V> in KV<K, Iterable<V>> and number each value. Though, with multiple trigger firings, you will indeed need the state API to keep a contiguous numbering.

Comment: What if we want the sequence generator to follow an oder, such as the sorted order of the context.element() value for example? Is that possible even in Beam? I couldn't figure out a way given the existing Beam sdk.